# How do I transform this dataset to not include counterbalancing?

Tags: r

If I have a dataset like this :

[sample dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lbdnX.png)

How do I transform the dataset to make something exactly like this?

[what I am looking for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y7p0K.png)

I was thinking of using pivot_longer() but I don't really know where to start at all.

If someone could help with this, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome. Please share your data using ``dput()`` or as a formatted table and not as images. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Data:

```
library(data.table)

df = data.table(groupA_avg=c(1,NA,2,NA), groupB_avg=c(NA,3,NA,4))

df
   groupA_avg groupB_avg
1:          1         NA
2:         NA          3
3:          2         NA
4:         NA          4
```

You could try something like:

```
rbind(df[!is.na(groupA_avg), avg:=groupA_avg][,"avg"], df[!is.na(groupB_avg), avg:=groupB_avg][,"avg"])
```

**Output:**

```
   avg
1:   1
2:   3
3:   2
4:   4
5:   1
6:   3
7:   2
8:   4
```

PS: in your case with mutiple cols

```
do.call("rbind", list(df[!is.na(groupA_avg), avg:=groupA_avg][,"avg"], 
                      df[!is.na(groupB_avg), avg:=groupB_avg][,"avg"],
                      and so on with the other columns))
```